# JAVA code visible in android APK - APK Analyzer

Tags: android, apk, proguard, obfuscation, apktool

I am trying to view APK contents using Android Studio's APK analyzer tool.
According to https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer, APK would contain dex files from which class information can be viewed.

With my sample application, I am able to see .java classes directly in the APK. Refer [APK files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc7Et.png).

I want to avoid having the JAVA classes as part of APK to reduce APK size and for security reasons.

Comment: `security reasons` what security reasons? You shouldn't ever put sensitive information in an app anyway. - When compiling, make sure you enable obfuscation and ProGuard/R8

Answer (score 0):

Use like this in your build.gradle -

```
android {
    buildTypes {
         release {
              // Enables code shrinking, obfuscation, and optimization for only
             // your project's release build type.
             minifyEnabled true

             // Enables resource shrinking, which is performed by the
             // Android Gradle plugin.
             shrinkResources true

             // Includes the default ProGuard rules files that are 
              packaged with
             // the Android Gradle plugin. To learn more, go to the 
              section about
             // R8 configuration files.
               proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile(
                'proguard-android-optimize.txt'),
                'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
...
```

}

Do read google Docs for better understanding. You will get a clear picture.

Follow this -

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code

Comment: Enabling proguard is an option. But APK should contain only dex files and not JAVA code right?

Comment: Anupam Bose, In addition to dex files there are JAVA files https://i.stack.imgur.com/gc7Et.png